# RavenDB: Use Fiddler to retrieve the structure of the queries sent to the database

Tags: c#, ravendb, dynamic-queries

Is it possible to use Fiddler 4 to retrieve the structure of the queries sent to RavendB (C#)? 
In fact, I am currently using session.Query() to write queries to manage the data stored in a RavenDB database. I would like to transform all these queries into session.Advanced.DocumentQuery() queries. But, some of these queries are complex. Is it possible to use fiddler to see how RavenDB transform the session.Query()  queries I run into session.Advanced.DocumentQuery() queries? If so, how can I proceed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you see all the queries if you enable logging? I think that Ravendb logs all queries in DEBUG-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can more easily get the string of the query by just calling `.ToString()` on the query object.

Alternatively, you can pipe everything through fiddler, by specifying http://localhost.fiddler:8080 as the db url in ravendb.

Comment: toString() is working. It helps me understand the structure of the query (session.Advanced.DocumentQuery()) that is processed by  ravenDB